# Coin Flip Streaks Challenge - Al Sweigart's Automate The Boring Stuff with python

Tags: python

Looking around the internet for the expected result to this challenge I have found different answers so that I'm not sure what is correct. I think my code looks ok and results in **1.5%** but differs from others. So I am looking for the correct answer to this.

Here's the challenge:

**Coin Flip Streaks**

*For this exercise, we’ll try doing an experiment. If you flip a coin 100 times and write down an “H” for each heads and “T” for each tails, you’ll create a list that looks like “T T T T H H H H T T.” If you ask a human to make up 100 random coin flips, you’ll probably end up with alternating head-tail results like “H T H T H H T H T T,” which looks random (to humans), but isn’t mathematically random. A human will almost never write down a streak of six heads or six tails in a row, even though it is highly likely to happen in truly random coin flips. Humans are predictably bad at being random. Write a program to find out how often a streak of six heads or a streak of six tails comes up in a randomly generated list of heads and tails. Your program breaks up the experiment into two parts: the first part generates a list of randomly selected 'heads' and 'tails' values, and the second part checks if there is a streak in it. Put all of this code in a loop that repeats the experiment 10,000 times so we can find out what percentage of the coin flips contains a streak of six heads or tails in a row. As a hint, the function call random.randint(0, 1) will return a 0 value 50% of the time and a 1 value the other 50% of the time. You can start with the following template:*

```
import random
numberOfStreaks = 0
for experimentNumber in range(10000):
    # Code that creates a list of 100 'heads' or 'tails' values.
    # Code that checks if there is a streak of 6 heads or tails in a row.
print('Chance of streak: %s%%' % (numberOfStreaks / 100))
```

Comment: Hi @CGO, welcome to the site. It's not very clear what your question is here. Can you clarify if you think you're getting the wrong answer or something? If your code is working fine, and you just want feedback on it, you probably want to ask on the [codereview.se] stack, not here. As for your code itself, it's not clear to me from the question wording if you're supposed to be counting the total number of streaks, or if you are supposed to only count a list with a streak once (that is, you're counting the number of lists that have streaks, not the number of streaks).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it should be to count _once_ any experiment that contains either streak. The reason is that the division by 100 in the template code is there because you would divide the count by the number of experiments (10000) then multiply by 100 to get the percentage and 100/10000 is 1/100. The percentage should be much higher than 1.5% - I get approx 80%. 1.5% is if you were trying to get 6 heads or 6 tails in 6 flips (0.5**6 * 100)

Comment: Hi! Yeah I'm looking for the answer, really. I tried including my code for feedback on it too, but I see now I might have posted it to the "code review" stack. I'll try editing the post.

Comment: The answer is approx 80%.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I believe to be a correct implementation of a solution to the problem. The problem is a little vague, but taken at face value and backed up by the logic that the template code calculates the final percentage by simply dividing by 100, it's straightforward. The divide by 100 is due to the fact that ((n/10000)*100) is the same as (n/100).

```
import random

n_experiments = 10000
n_streaks = 0
six_heads = 'H' * 6
six_tails = 'T' * 6

for experiment in range(n_experiments):
    run = ''.join(random.choices('HT', k=100))
    if six_heads in run or six_tails in run:
        n_streaks += 1

print(f'Total runs with at least one streak: {n_streaks}')
print(f'Chance of streak: {(n_streaks / n_experiments * 100):.2f}%')
```

This code generates a string of length 100 containing randomly generated characters H or T. It is easy to search a string for a run of characters simply by using the `in` operator e.g. `'HHHHHH' in 'THTHHHHHHTTTTHTH'` is True.

This code consistently reports the chance to be slightly more than 80% that a run of 6 heads or tails will be present in each 100 flips.

If you change `k` to 6 such that each experiment has only 6 flips then the result is approx 3%, which is consistent with the calculated probability of 3.125% = (1 * 0.5**5) * 100.

Comment: That was amazing!!! Thank you, I also think it was somewhat vague.